# Changing a font style in ggcorplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to change a font style for correlation shown in a correlation plot created using ggcorplot? I understand one can change the size and color of correlation, but I am having difficulty finding out a solution to change a font style.

e.g., correlation between drat and mpg is **0.7** and I would like to change **0.7** into a different font styl (e.g., from Arial to Times New Roman).

```
library(ggcorrplot)

# Compute a correlation matrix
data(mtcars)
corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

# Compute a matrix of correlation p-values
p.mat <- cor_pmat(mtcars)

# Compute a plot
ggcorrplot(corr,
           hc.order = TRUE,
           type = "lower",
           lab = TRUE)
```

The resulting plot looks like this:[image: the image shows a correlation plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do some hacks or manipulations on the `ggplot` object returned by `ggcorrplot`, i.e. you could override the default `mapping` used by the `geom_text` layer (which is the second layer) which add the text label, e.g. below I use an `ifelse` to set the `fontface` to "bold" for drat and mpg and "plain" otherwise:

```r
library(ggcorrplot)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

data(mtcars)
corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)

p <- ggcorrplot(corr,
  hc.order = TRUE,
  type = "lower",
  lab = TRUE
)

p$layers[[2]]$mapping <- aes(Var1, Var2,
  fontface = ifelse(Var2 == "mpg" & Var1 == "drat", "bold", "plain")
)

p
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! Based on your response, I played with geom_text and got what I was looking. I used geom_text(aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, label=value), family="Times") to change the font from default to Times New Roman.